# Android - How to improve ListView performance when setting Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar in Activity?

Tags: android, performance, listview, scroll, translucency

I have an activity with `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` set as the activity's style attribute in the manifest.xml.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

I need that, because when launching the activity, I animate the rootlayout of this activity from the bottom to the top (like the `ModalPresentation` on iPhone) and I don't want to have a black background during this animation.

Everythings works, but the performance of the `ListView` I put in this rootlayout is very slow after applying the translucent theme.

I already tried setting BackgroundColors of the `ListView` and the rootlayout, but it seems, that android still considers the transparency while drawing.

Comment: Could you please post the code that you run for that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_4444);` in `onCreate()`?